# How to resolve the error : "MyClass.INSTANCE" is not a statement when I try to instantiate a singleton class in Java?

Tags: java, enums, singleton, instantiation

I have a Java Singleton class as :

```
public enum MyClass{
   INSTANCE;

   private MyClass(){
     init();
   } 

   private static void init(){
     System.out.println("Singleton Class initiated");
   }
}
```

When I try to instantiate the class by :

```
MyClass.INSTANCE;
```

I get an error that it is not a statement.

However, the following works, which is not ideal for production code:

```
System.out.println(MyClass.INSTANCE);
```

Is there a way to initiate the enum singleton class properly, without calling any other dummy API of the class?

Comment: `MyClass instance = MyClass.INSTANCE;`

Comment: Thank you! Please add it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Just to clarify: you want some code that doesn't actually do anything with your class yet, but that ensures that the class is actually initialized, right?

Comment: @JoachimSauer : That's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment: simply declare it in this way:

```
MyClass instance = MyClass.INSTANCE;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just state class ( or enum in your case) isn't a valid Java statement.

You can create an object as @Lorelorelore suggested

```
MyClass instance = MyClass.INSTANCE;
```

Or if you want to call `init()` maybe change its signature

```
public void init(){
    System.out.println("Singleton Class initiated");
}
```

And call the method directly:

```
MyClass.INSTANCE.init();
```